# DataTable styling for Previous 1 2 Next tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

In the examples of DataTable, there is button for `Previous 1 2 3... Next` tabs. In examples it's nicely ordered but they do not show how they did it. In my example these tabs are not nicely ordered and also shifted  to left side. Please see the attached image.

How to style these tabs as they show in examples?

[image]

Comment: There is a stylesheet which is included as part of Datatables which does this for you. You need to include it. If you already have, then the styles from it are being overridden by your own rules. You need to find the relevant ones and change them.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you for the comment. What is that `stylesheet` name?

Comment: See the setup guide on their site for details: https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

DataTable plugin provides an API documentation and example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "pagingType": "full_numbers"
    } );
} );
```

For more details, you can visit the following pages.

https://datatables.net/reference/option/pagingType

https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination